# How to Filter and Copy Org Mode Entries Matching a Specific Expression in Emacs?

Tags: org-mode, match

I am trying to efficiently filter and copy entries with specific headings in an Org mode file using Emacs. I want to extract all entries whose headings match a particular regular expression. However, I am relatively new to Emacs and Org mode, and I am not sure about the most effective way to achieve this.

I have attempted to use the org-match-sparse-tree command, but I'm unsure how to copy the filtered entries after this step. Are there any built-in functions or packages that can facilitate this process? Can someone provide a step-by-step guide or a code snippet to accomplish this task? I would greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations on how to effectively filter and copy Org mode entries matching a specified expression in Emacs.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or guidance!

Comment: Copy them where? To a list in memory? To another file? I guess what's missing is: what are you planning to do with the filtered entries *after* you have got them?